# Reshpe columns of Pandas dataframe in a single cell for unique id

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

As shown in snapshot I have a output (left side).
I want to make the output or dataframe like the desired output.

[image]

Comment: We will need more information in order to help you.  Please edit your question to include relevant sources and code. You may find this link useful: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  :-)

Comment: I edited the questions